# Load Properties or XML in glassfish web service

Tags: java, glassfish, jax-ws

I've got a basic glassfish web service and I'm trying to load some properties from WEB-INF folder.
However,

Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader().getResource("test.properties")
this.getClass().getResource("test.properties");

don't seem to be searching in the right directories. Replacing test.properties with ".", i get the directory
file:/C:/Program%20Files%20(x86)/glassfish-3.1.2/glassfish/domains/domain1/lib/classes/
which is completely empty.

How do i load property files from the java layer in a web service like this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put it in WEB-INF/classes and ask for "/test.properties"